# .htaccess continues to internal redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm being completely out witted by the voodoo that is mod_rewrite. We have recently relocated to a new ubuntu server on aws, and all appears to be working fine except one .htaccess file. This file was working great on the previous server but it's working well on the new server.

The page concerned is testing.sonicdad.com/members/admin/. This should redirect to testing.sonicdad.com/members/admin.php and not testing.sonicdad.com/members/admin/index.php

I've stripped the .htaccess down to just the relevant code for this page, and still have the problem. Please see below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /members

## Append Trailing "/" to URL if absent ##
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /members/$1/    [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^admin/$  admin.php [L]
```

This is the relate part of the logs

```
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/members/admin/ -> admin/
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'admin/'
[rewrite:trace4] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/members/admin/' pattern='!-f' => matched
[rewrite:trace4] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] RewriteCond: input='/members/admin/' pattern='!(.*)/$' => not-matched
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/members/admin/ -> admin/
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] applying pattern '^admin/$' to uri 'admin/'
[rewrite:trace2] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] rewrite 'admin/' -> 'admin.php'
[rewrite:trace3] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] add per-dir prefix: admin.php -> /var/www/html/members/admin.php
[rewrite:trace2] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/html/members/ with /members
[rewrite:trace4] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] add subst prefix: admin.php -> /members/admin.php
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e168600a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] internal redirect with /members/admin.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e0ced10a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] pass through /var/www/html/members/admin/index.html
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e0ced10a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] pass through /var/www/html/members/admin/index.cgi
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e0ced10a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] pass through /var/www/html/members/admin/index.pl
[rewrite:trace1] [pid 26730] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 121.202.24.118:13894] 121.202.24.118 - - [testing.sonicdad.com/sid#7f8e16990038][rid#7f8e0ced10a0/subreq] [perdir /var/www/html/members/] pass through /var/www/html/members/admin/index.php
```

The issue appears to be the internal redirect. I to stop this I have tried modifying the flag to [END]. I have also tried variations of the following:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !=200
```

Please could someone tell me how to stop this internal redirect after the rule is applied.

Thanks

Comment: "[INTERNAL REDIRECT" just means the URL has been rewritten. Are you **sure** this isn't admin.php that's redirecting to the admin/index.php file?

Comment: @Jon Lin Sorry I don't understand. The .htaccess is rewriting the admin/ to admin.php which is correct. But then mod_rewrite appears to then run check /members/admin.php again and modifies it to /members/admin/index.php. A least that was my understanding of the logs.

Comment: Can it be a MultiViews issue? Try it with `Options -MultiViews` (though this is just a blind guess). Also, you mention you've moved servers; have you checked how the httpd.conf files are different?

Comment: I tried adding MultiViews but no joy

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other .htaccess files in play here? Like in any of your sub-directories like /admin/ ?

Also try swapping the last two lines of your htaccess file around,

```
RewriteRule ^admin/$  admin.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   /members/$1/    [L,R=301]
```

As far as I know the Switch [L] means its the last rule to be used. Try removing that too.

Answer (score 0):

We where unable to fix this issue so we modified the folder structure so there was no replica filenames and folder names ie admin.php and admin/.

This actually means we have a cleaner more descriptive folder structure which I'm happy with